# Expand the Metal Gear Solid tags to reflect 35 character tag limit

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

Since the 35 character tag limit is long enough for all of the full game names in the *Metal Gear Solid* series, the following tags should be renamed:

- [metal-gear-solid-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-2) → [metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty)
- [metal-gear-solid-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-3) → [metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater)
- [metal-gear-solid-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4) → [metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots)
- [metal-gear-solid-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-hd) → [metal-gear-solid-hd-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-hd-collection)
- [mgs-5-motherbase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-motherbase) → [metal-gear-solid-5-motherbase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-motherbase)
- [mgs-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-online) → [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online)

There are also a few outstanding synonym requests on meta:

- Make [metal-gear-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-series) a synonym of [metal-gear-solid-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-series) ([discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11197/47878))
- Make [metal-gear-online-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-online-3) a synonym of [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online) ([discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11238/47878))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**These are all done:**

- [metal-gear-solid-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-2) → [metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-2-sons-of-liberty)
- [metal-gear-solid-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-3) → [metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater)
- [metal-gear-solid-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4) → [metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots)
- [metal-gear-solid-hd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-hd) → [metal-gear-solid-hd-collection](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-hd-collection)
- [mgs-5-motherbase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-motherbase) → [metal-gear-solid-5-motherbase](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-motherbase)
- [mgs-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mgs-5-online) → [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online)
- [metal-gear-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-series) → [metal-gear-solid-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-series)
- [metal-gear-online-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-online-3) → [metal-gear-solid-5-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metal-gear-solid-5-online)